# Check contents of a string and clear contents

Tags: c#, if-statement, windows-phone-8

I am trying to find a way to check the contents of a string in my WindowsPhone 8.0 Silverlight app.

So far I have the following code:

```
if(MyURI2.Contains(App.MyPurchaseLink_URI))
{
    // TODO
}
```

`App.MyPurchaseLink_URI` is set later in the code and will contain a url which is then passed through to the following page where it is retrieved as `MyURI2`.

On the users second visit to this page, I would like to check the contents of `App.MyPurchaseLink_URI` and if it contains any data within it, I would like to clear that value and continue executing the rest of my code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: A concrete example of the values to be removed will be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Tried some things out and the following seemed to work.

```
if(MyURI2.Contains(App.MyPurchaseLink_URI))
{
    MyURI2 = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use stringbuilder class for changing the value of a string because the string class is an immutable class. 
Declaration is 
`StringBuilder MyURI2="";`

```
if(MyURI2.Contains(App.MyPurchaseLink_URI)){
MyURI2.clear();    }
```

now the string gets empty